# Get data from other table using relationship table

Tags: mysql

i want to get the value of a column from table x using table z's row id 
Where table y is maintaining relationship of both x and y

```
**table: x**
sid  |  name

**table: z**
gid  |  name

**table: y**
id   |  sid  |  gid
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Try [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* FROM x, y, z WHERE z.name LIKE 'Some text' AND z.gid = y.gid AND y.sid = x.sid;
```

This SQL query should do the trick for you.
The code is untested though.